# ASP.NET MVC Dummy Repository once working than make Database. Is it wise?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project. Completed conceptual model of Database is done in EntityFrameWork. Database is not created yet. Should I make a dummy Records with dummy repository and go on development without creating database and once all done than just created the DB and turn dummy repositories to live? . Is it right decision or should I start making database to work with it from the start?

Thanks

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with using a database for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with working against a dummy repository.  In many ways this is a way of abstracting out your data layer (i.e. EF) from your UI.  This should be the case anyhow if you are Unit Testing your models, controllers, etc.  One cautionary note (from experience) make sure you're not coding to the hard coded dummy data, real data in the DB may (or will) not conform to the inherent assumptions your hard coded data will most likely have.

Comment: ConfusedGreek I don't understand your last point of Caution. If I use dummy data than most likely will be hardcoded data username = "AAAAA" etc.

Comment: it depends on your application/data.  But one of the dangers of hard coded data is that while developing your app against it the data doesn't really change so it's easy to unknowingly code to the dummy data.